# Cart price not updated on cart page - Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

Cart is not getting updated when the product price in the cart is changed from the backend

can you please help!

Comment: have u checked  at on default   2.1.7 version

Comment: Try to clear cache and reindexing data :P

Comment: yes i have checked in default 2.1.7 @amit

Comment: already do that! @paresha

Comment: try to write custom action in etc/section.xml

Comment: Have you done any customization to cart items? Generally it works fine with indexers up to date..